# How do I get selecteditem from ListView in XAML?

Tags: c#, xaml, mvvm, uwp

This may be a duplicate. But I have tried everything I could find, and I cannot make it work.

Why does this not work? SelectedCourse is allways null. I have tested everything else, and it works fine. It is just getting the selected Item who is the problem.

This is my ViewModel:

```
public Course SelectedCourse { get; set; }

public async Task CoursesListViewClick(object sender, ItemClickEventArgs e)
        {
            var students = await coursesDataAccess.GetCourseStudentsAsync(SelectedCourse.CourseID); //THIS IS NULL
            foreach (Student s in students)
                CourseStudents.Add(s);
        }
```

This is my XAML code:

```
           <ListView Grid.Column="0"
                      x:Name="lvCourses"
                      IsItemClickEnabled="True"
                      DataContext="{x:Bind ViewModel}"
                      ItemsSource="{Binding Courses, Mode=OneWay}"
                      SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedCourse, Mode=TwoWay}"
                      ItemClick="{x:Bind ViewModel.CoursesListViewClick}"
                      Margin="10">
                <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate x:DataType="model:Course">
                        <StackPanel Height="250">
                            <TextBlock
                                FontSize="50"
                                HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                                VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                Text="{x:Bind Name}"
                                Style="{StaticResource TitleTextBlockStyle}"/>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListView.ItemTemplate>
            </ListView>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> > Why does this not work? SelectedCourse is allways null.

Since you have bound the SelectedItem property and ItemClick event, when you click the listViewItem, it will first trigger the `CoursesListViewClick` method which bound with the ItemClick event and then trigger the setter method of SelectedCourse to set the value. So in the CoursesListViewClick  method, the SelectedCourse hasn't been assigned a value, it is always null.

The `e.ClickedItem` from CoursesListViewClick  method represents the current item you clicked, you can directly use it to operate.

```
public async Task CoursesListViewClick(object sender, ItemClickEventArgs e)
{
    Course selectedCourse = e.ClickedItem as Course;
    var students = await coursesDataAccess.GetCourseStudentsAsync(selectedCourse.CourseID); //THIS IS NULL
    foreach (Student s in students)
        CourseStudents.Add(s);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if you use:
`listView.ItemTapped += async (sender, e) =>
{
e.Item;
}`
you can then manipulate what you want to do depending on the item id

Hope this helps!

Comment: I want to do most of my code in the ViewModel. Not in "Code behind".